# Viewport is changing zoom when Flexbox container is running out of space

Tags: html, css

My page starts to change zoom and layout gets slightly messed up when I have a hardcoded width on items located in a Flexbox container (make a very narrow Chrome Devtools responsive window). The problem starts when I make my viewing area narrower than the 300px. Unfortunately, you can't see this problem when running this inside an iframe on jsfiddle - it has to be ran "on it's own", my html block needs to be THE top html block.

Here's the jsfiddle for reference still:

https://jsfiddle.net/elijahww/9e1u7ptr/

```
<html><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #productShowcaseContainer {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        .contentContainer {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
        }

        #productShowcaseTitle {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }


        #productShowcaseThumbnailContainer {
            flex: 1;
            background-color: darkseagreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
<div id="productShowcaseContainer">
    <div id="productShowcaseTitle"></div>

    <div class="contentContainer">
        <div id="productShowcaseThumbnailContainer" style="padding: 10px;">
            <input style="width:300px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

I don't know how to make this work.

here is a gif:
[image]

Comment: can you show a picture?

Comment: @xmaster i pasted a GIF.

Comment: what happens if you add this code `align-items: stretch;`

Comment: @xmaster, i just tried that too - it had no effect. Ugh.

Answer (score 2):

This might be happening because you have **hard-coded width of input field as 300px** and trying to zoom screen width beyond this.
If you really want to have responsive layout then you should be using flex-layout properly and set `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` property of each layout element.

These properties are responsible for handling responsive behaviour of flex-elements.
To Read more about flex layout follow this link [Flex tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Problem is - i refactored the site with Flexbox html, body, top level container. The rest of the application (100 pages at least) has a smorgasbord of css. The offending ones are the hard coded widths. It's a ton of elements, css with it. (call it legacy code)

Comment: For properly integrating flex-layout you need to update the existing css of hard-coded elements, I dont think so there is any other workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to give some parent container `overflow-x: auto`

```css
body {
            background-color: #3d5d6a;
        }
        #container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        .main-content-container {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
        }

        #top-header-container {
            padding: 10px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            /*align-content: stretch;*/
            display: flex;
            justify-content: stretch;
        }


        #main-content-inner {
            flex: 1;
            background-color: darkseagreen;
        }

        .responsive-table {
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
<div id="container">
    <div id="top-header-container">
        <div class="responsive-table">
            <input style="width:400px;" value="hard coded to 400px">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="main-content-container">
        <div id="main-content-inner" style="padding: 10px;">
          test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was when one of containers had flex-direction: column. After changing to row the problem disappeared.